# Express Multiple res.json(); with middlewares

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm trying to build a stateless API using JWT. I have a middleware function in my Router which checks if the JWT has expired, if it has, a new Token with a new timestamp is generated on the fly.

I would like to pass the new token along with the response in the JSON Object. My current approach is like this, but it of course doesn't work:

```
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
   // JWT Expired
   // Generate new JWT
   res.write(JSON.stringify({token: token});
   next();
});


router.get('/securedRoute' function(req, res) {
   // Fetch data
   res.json({data: data});
});
```

:

```
// Output should be:
{token: 'erg34jlkgjre.3f4fknlj.34f3', data: ['sdfa', 'sdf']}
```

It would be nice to find a way, where I don't have to alter all of my existing code and check if there is a new token.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: this may be a dumb question, but if you're going to set a fresh token anytime you discover an expired token, why not just turn off the token expiration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to add the authorization token in the `response` header:

```
router.use((request, response, next) => {
  response.setHeader('Token', token);

  next();
});

router.get('/securedRoute', (request, response) => {
  response.json({ data: data });
});
```

Alternatively, you could always add the token to the `request` and then conditionally add the `request.token` into all of your routes like the previous answer suggested. Unfortunately that would mean that you need to modify all of your routes.

---

As an alternative you could override the `response.json` method and manually inject the token if it exists. In doing so, you wouldn't need to modify any of your routes.

```
router.use((request, response, next) => {
  request.token = token;

  ((proxied) => {
    response.json = function (data) {
      if (request && request.token) {
        data.token = request.token;
      }

      return proxied.call(this, data);
    };
  })(response.json);

  next();
});

router.get('/securedRoute', (request, response) => {
  response.json({ data: data });
});
```

In the example above, the `response.json` method is overridden in the middleware. This is done by passing a reference to the old `response.json` method and then calling it after conditionally injecting the token into the payload.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is assuming you want to achieve that in same method

Rather than writing the token in middleware do something like

```
(req,res,next)=>{
  req.token = newToken;
  next();
}
```

And in your route

```
res.json(req.token ? {token:req.token,data:data} : {data:data});
```

Comment: That is a possibility, but that would require me to change every single route I have setup so far.
But maybe that's my only option

Comment: Okay here is a better method then, just change the middleware and set authorization headers rather. It won't conflict with the code that you have in routes, all you would need is a handle on your client side js to check the headers

Comment: Also have a look at https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/